# how to check form hidden field is empty or not and then only send respected request parameter to servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically i have one section having 6 Select box like this i am populating them dynamically using ajax but number of select field populated changes according to servlet response like some time 2 selectbox shown or sometime 5 ,4 ,3 etc... i am hiding others selectbox that are not polulated. Now i want to get there value into respective input hidden filed when selected on button click event and i want to pass only displayed selectbox value to servelt not all

```
<div id="section-2" class="section-content"> 
    <fieldset id="field-1">
        <label for="field-1">Data 1</label>
        <select id="factor-1"></select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="field-2">
        <label for="field-2">Data 2</label>
        <select id="factor-2"></select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="field-3">
        <label for="field-3">Data 2</label>
        <select id="factor-3"></select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="field-4">
        <label for="field-4">Data 4</label>
        <select id="factor-4"></select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="field-5">
        <label for="field-5">Data 5</label>
        <select id="factor-5"></select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="field-6">
        <label for="field-6">Data 6</label>
        <select id="factor-6"></select>
    </fieldset>

    <button type="button" id="section2-next"> Next </button>

    <input type="text" id="data-1-Id"/>
    <input type="text" id="data-2-Id"/>
    <input type="text" id="data-3-Id"/>
    <input type="text" id="data-4-Id"/>
    <input type="text" id="data-5-Id"/>
    <input type="text" id="data-6-Id"/>

</div>
```

And here is my `$.ajax()` call..

```
$("#section2-next").click(function(){

    var param1= $("#data-1-Id").val();
    var param2= $("#data-2-Id").val();
    var param3= $("#data-3-Id").val();
    var param4= $("#data-4-Id").val();
    var param5= $("#data-5-Id").val();
    var param6= $("#data-6-Id").val();
    // here i am having problem how to pass only filled input filed value not all 6  parammeters on every ajax request.........
    var dataString = 'param1='+param1+"&param2="+param2+"&param3="+param3+"&param4="+param4+"&param5="+param5+"&param6="+param6;
    console.log(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type:"Post",
        url:"GetPrice",
        datatype:"json",
        data : dataString,
        success: function(data){  
            //  var price = data.asset;
            var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
            var price = parsed[0].FormattedPrice;
            $('#price').empty().text(price);
        }
    });

});
```

and also how to check that parameter exists in servlet ?

Comment: `$('select').filter(':visible').serialize()` , this way you can pass only the visible select to the ajax function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your input in a form like this:

`<form name="section2-next" id="section2-next">`
`<input type="text" id="data-1-Id"/>`
`<input type="text" id="data-2-Id"/>`
`<input type="text" id="data-3-Id"/>><input type="text" id="data-4-Id"/>`
`<input type="submit"value="submit!"/>`
`<!-- dont forget the input of type submit-->`
`</form>`

> then use  $("#section2-next").submit(function(event){
>
> event.preventDefault();// dont forget this line..
>
> //instead of  $("#section2-next").click(function(){

next

> // for your dataString
>
> `var dataString = {param1 : $("#data-1-Id").val() || '', param2 : $("#data-2-Id").val() || ''};// up until param6`

and

> // for var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
>
> `var parsed = $.parseJSON(data);`

finally,

> // in your php file
>   `<?php`
>   `echo json_encode($_POST);`
>   `?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
       var dataString ="";
    if ($("#data-1-Id").val() != '' )
    { dataString = 'param1='+param1; }

    ...
dataString =dataString+ #2
    .do the same for all 
    ...
```

Comment: thanks for ans but how to convert dataString into json format